# Using XAML markup and binding, how would I display a list of items and list of subitems under each item?

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, itemscontrol

I have a list of questions in an array and each question type has a list of answers which is a list of strings. I need to display each question and under each question the answers assigned to the question with a `CheckBox` for each answer. I have the questions displaying on the form, but have not been able to get the answers up. Below is what I have for markup binding the questions only:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IcQuestions">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="questions:QuestionAnswers">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Question Type" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,10,5,0" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding QuestionType}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Question}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What platform is it? WPF, WinRT, UWP?

Answer (score 0):

There is special classes for displaying grouped list.

For Windows Phone it is [`LongListSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector(v=vs.105).aspx)

For Windows 10 `ItemsControl` has build-in [grouping support via `GroupStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx)

For WPF `ItemsControl` has also [`GroupStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

All approach restrict your data to be [IGrouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/api/system.linq.igrouping-2).
With properly prepared data your markup for `ItemsControl.GroupStyle` would be something like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IcQuestions">
<ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="questions:QuestionAnswers">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Question Type" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,10,5,0" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding QuestionType}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Question}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Checkbox Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>            
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Using the markup above and the correct data structure, I get the answers with the checkbox but I am not getting the question type and text to appear.